# Bind Tree View Control in ASP.NET 3.5 with Remote PC

Tags: asp.net, treeview, .net-3.5

I am making a ASP.NET Web Application in 3.5. Is it possible to have a Tree View control that binds with a remote PC (via IP, something like //10.227.124.53/SharePath/Documents) and shows the files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that method is not possible.  I am doing the exact same thing. I use a wcf service on the remote machine and call functions to build the tree on demand as the user expands the tree. It works well and you won't have any user permissions issues either what means it will just work.